# How to remove values in spreadsheet B based on values in spreadsheet A?

Tags: windows, excel, vba, automation

I am working on automating a business process using excel macros in VB and I have it all completed except for one part. I have an inventory sheet that I would like updated upon running the macro. What it would do is search an order file for part numbers, compare those part numbers with the inventory sheet, and then remove inventory quantities within the inventory sheet based on the values found within the order sheet. These are in two separate workbooks. Here is an example of how it looks:

```
Spreadsheet A - Order Sheet: 

A         B            C   
Part #:   Description: Quantity
123456    Item 1       1
1234567   Item 2       1
12345678  Item 3       1

Spreadsheet B - Inventory Sheet: 

A         B            C   
Part #:   Description: Quantity
123456    Item 1       580
1234567   Item 2       790
12345678  Item 3       578
```

So this program would subtract values in Spreadsheet B - Column C based on the values in Spreadsheet A - Column C and Column A

In the order sheet even if a customer orders multiple items it shows each purchase as a separate item, so this program would only need to remove quantities of one at a time.

I'm rather new to this type of Excel Automation so any input would be greatly appreciated. I've been looking into Vlookup but from what I understand it only looks for information and displays existing values.

Comment: What code have to tried so far?

Comment: I currently have not tried any code for this portion as I am unsure where to start. I have been researching different functions but am looking for some insight. @D_Zab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to remove the "Orders" from the "Inventory" every time you run a macro, the right thing to do should be, in words, *for each line in "Orders", search the corresponding object into the inventory and subtract the quantity*.

In code, it's as easy as in words:

```
For j = 2 To Sheets("Orders").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    For k = 2 To Sheets("Inventory").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        If Sheets("Orders").Range("A" & j).Value = Sheets("Inventory").Range("A" & k).Value Then '<-- when the object is found
            Sheets("Inventory").Range("C" & k).Value = Sheets("Inventory").Range("C" & k).Value - Sheets("Orders").Range("C" & j).Value '<-- subtract order's value
            Exit For '<-- you don't need to loop any further after having found the object
        End If
    Next k
Next j
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize I had not got back to it yet. Looking at the code, it would appear it does not matter which order these items are in yes? And thank you for your correction with my wording. That does make more sense

Comment: @ReaganKirby you're right, it doesn't matter the order.

Answer (score 1):

Press alt+f11

right click project on left and insert a module.

type in the mane code pane:

```
 Public Sub UpdateInventory
    'place some code like
    for n1=0 to 1000
        for n2=0 to 100
InventoryItemCode= Sheets("Inventory").range("A1").offset(n1,0).value
OrderCode=Sheets("Orders").range("A1").offset(n2,0).value
          If InventoryItemCode=OrderCode  then
           'etc....
          End if
        Next n2
    NEXT n1
    End sub
```

see google for troubleshooting